# Sort by value, where value is in another collection and ID is stored in collection where we apply sort

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have next situation.

In `parameters` collection I have documents which have key `groups` where values are `ids` of documents from another collection. That is something like a FOREIGN key which references to another collection.

In another collection we have documents that corresponds to the '_ids' which are stored in main `parameters` collection.

Here is one sample document from `parameters` collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("538726134ba2222c0c0248b6"),
    "name" : "Potta",
    "groups" : [ 
        "54c91b2c4ba222182e636943"
    ]
}
```

I need to sort by groups, but as you can see in main collection groups values are ID's, but I want to sort by group names.

Here is one sample collection from `groups` collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c91b2c4ba222182e636943"),
    "name" : "Group 01",
}
```

Is this possible to achieve in Mongo DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the datas are

```
> db.parameters.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cac0cd0b5a1ffab1bd6c12"), "name" : "potta", "groups" : [ "
123", "234" ] }
> db.groups.find({})
{ "_id" : "123", "name" : "Group01" }
{ "_id" : "234", "name" : "Group02" }
```

Under `mongodb 3.2`, you can do it through [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to perform a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database, then to `sort` the group name as below.

```
> db.parameters.aggregate([
                          {$unwind: '$groups'}, 
                          {$lookup: {
                                    from: 'groups', 
                                    localField: 'groups', 
                                    foreignField: '_id', 
                                    as: 'gr'}},
                           {$sort: {'gr.name': 1}}])
```

---

For under `3.2`, please try to do it as following

```
> var pa = db.parameters.find({});
> pa.forEach(function(doc) {
                var ret = db.groups
                            .find({_id: {$in: doc.groups}})
                            .sort({name: 1}); 
                ret.forEach(printjson)
});
```

---

Or you could do it through [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce) as below

```
// emit group id from parameters collection
> var map_param = function() { 
            var that = this; 
            this.groups.forEach(function(g){emit(that._id, g);})};

// emit group id and name from group collection
> var map_group = function() {emit(this._id, this.name);}

// combine those results from map functions above
> var r = function(k, v) {
            var result = {id: '', name: ''};
            v.forEach(function(val){
                   if (val.id !== null){ result.id = val;} 
                   if (val.name !== null) {result.name = val;}
            }); 
            return result;};

> db.parameters.mapReduce(map_param, r, {out: {reduce: 'joined'}})

> db.groups.mapReduce(map_group, r, {out: {reduce: 'joined'}, sort: {name: 1}})
```

Eventually, the sorted results are in the `joined` collection.

Comment: We are using mongo 3.0.3

Comment: mongo-3.0 can only do single collection aggregate.

Comment: You wrote two examples. First is for greater than 3.2 version and second is for under 3.2 version ?

Comment: @PottaG, yes, the second one is used for under 3.2 version.

Comment: For doc.groups I'm getting key value pairs because groups is array. I need the value of that array, but not sure how to achieve that. Thank you anyway. @zangw

Comment: @PottaG, given `groups` data as `> db.grouparr.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cadb9c0b5a1ffab1bd6c13"), "groups" : [ { "id" : "123", "na
me" : "Group02" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cadbac0b5a1ffab1bd6c14"), "groups" : [ { "id" : "234", "na
me" : "Group01" } ] }`
`> db.grouparr.find({'groups.id': {$in: ['123', '234']}}) `
`{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cadb9c0b5a1ffab1bd6c13"), "groups" : [ { "id" : "123", "na
me" : "Group02" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56cadbac0b5a1ffab1bd6c14"), "groups" : [ { "id" : "234", "na
me" : "Group01" } ] }`

Comment: @PottaG, if your `groups` data is more complicated, maybe you could ask another question..

Comment: @zangw I understand that it works and you write me an example with dummy data. You probably didn't understand my question. 

In our example: "doc.groups" return pair key => value, but we need only value. 

That is why we are getting error:
"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $in needs an array",

I tried to access to that value with doc.groups0, doc.groups.0, doc.groups[0] but it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104160/discussion-between-zangw-and-pottag).